# Using Droid as a computer microphone via USB?

Tags: usb, microphone

Is it possible to use my Droid as a computer microphone (for Skype, Teamspeak, etc) via the USB cord? If not, does anyone know of a Teamspeak client app?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 10):

There are all sorts of apps that enable you to use your phone's camera and mic on your PC over Wi-fi or USB.

Here are some examples:

- [DroidCam](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dev47apps.droidcam)
- [IP Webcam](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pas.webcam)

Answer (score 6):

The App [Microphone](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.bitplane.android.microphone) allows this. Just do it by 3.5mm cord; it's way easier.

Comment: Very useful stuff :)

Answer (score 2):

Sure... you just have to choose between hacking the phone or hacking the PC.

Via hacking the PC:

Enable USB debugging on the phone.  Install the SDK and get adb working.  Set up an adb port forward to the phone.  Write an apk which listens on a local network port and upon connection opens the microphone and pushes samples through the forwarded 'network' socket.  The hard part: on the PC, write a "microphone driver" which gets its data by connecting to the program on the android through the adb port forward.  You could also do the same thing substituting a wifi network for the adb-usb.

Via hacking the phone:

Compile a new USB kernel driver which presents the expected interface for a USB microphone, and have it gets its data from the microphone.  If going to this much trouble, you might as well make it into a USB webcam.  Root and serious coding required.

Answer (score 1):

[WO Virtual Mic](http://www.wirelessorange.com/womic/) 1.39€ + you need to install a client

Answer (score 0):

The answer is "No" - at least not without a dedicated app (if such exists).

BTW, I can understand wanting to do this via Bluetooth, but via USB? Why?

Comment: The app would have to route this through debugging info and have a program pic it up.

Answer (score 0):

[Senstic](https://market.android.com/developer?pub=Senstic) [PocketAudio Microphone](https://www.senstic.com/android/pocketaudio/pocketaudio.aspx), plus you need to install the PocketControl software on your PC (or Mac)

Comment: A link to the app might improve this answer. :)

Comment: just editing the post might save time :)