# How to use phone as camera and microphone for PC via ADB?

Tags: adb, camera, microphone

There are many previous questions asking about how to use the phone as camera and microphone for PC. For example:

- [Use my Android phone as the camera and microphone for PowerPoint slide recording](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/234510/94084)
- [Using Droid as a computer microphone via USB?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/8492/94084)

However, all the answer involve installing an app in the phone. In my experience, [DroidCam](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dev47apps.droidcam&hl=en&gl=VN) and IP Webcam are way too lagged. I cannot use them for online conversations, like using with Zoom. I think if there is a way to do that via ADB, then it will be much faster. We have such solutions for [projecting phone's screen](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/5652/94084).

Is there a way to do so? If no, then why is that?

My Android version is 7.1 (SDK 25).

Answer (score -1):

You can use the combination of `scrcpy` and `sndcpy`. both uses adb.
scrcpy github: https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy
sndcpy github: https://github.com/rom1v/sndcpy

Comment: Your answer is too short and mainly consists of two links. Please extend it and describe in details how the two tools can be used to use the phone as camera and microphone.

Comment: sndcpy only works for Android 10 and above